# message pack - how to find the represented string?

Tags: c++, messagepack

in the message pack website :

[Message Pack](http://msgpack.org/)

there is "Try" link above where it shows me how long is the representing string for the data.

I have a small script that is based on the examples presented in the message pack git hub

```
#include <msgpack.hpp>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main(void) {
    using namespace std;

    msgpack::sbuffer buffer;

    msgpack::packer<msgpack::sbuffer> pk(&buffer);
    pk.pack_map(2);
    pk.pack(string("SerialNumber"));
    pk.pack(123456789);
    pk.pack(string("Date"));
    pk.pack("1.4.14");



    //deserialize

    msgpack::unpacker pac;
    pac.reserve_buffer(buffer.size());
    memcpy(pac.buffer(),buffer.data(),buffer.size());
    pac.buffer_consumed(buffer.size());


    msgpack::unpacked result;
    while(pac.next(&result))
    {
        cout<<result.get()<<endl<<endl;

    }
```

works great but I want to retrive the String that is represented behind the packed data. just like in the "Try!" link. how can I find it ?

thank you

Comment: anyone? I really need help with this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to retrieve the String that is represented behind the packed data

What you can do is print the content of the simple buffer in hex format:

```
const char *data = buffer.data();
for (int i = 0; i < buffer.size(); i++)
    printf("%02x ", (unsigned char) data[i]);
```